# Is there any auto-completion facility for gradlew?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've recently migrated from a Windows/Eclipse build environment to an Ubuntu/Android Studio setup for my Android projects.

I prefer to use the command line for release builds. In order to see the available tasks, I need to type `gradlew tasks` on the command line. I then need to remember the option I want, such as `gradlew assembleRelease` or `gradlew installRelease`.

Is there any facility, (possibly a script?) which would enable something like Ubuntu's 'hit the tab' feature which allows an auto-completion set of options based on the input so far?

Comment: you can try this [https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8694399](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8694399)

Comment: @Alex - thank you for that link, it works well. If it were to be an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: I recently released https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion which provides much faster completion for bash and zsh, CLI options and Gradle properties, and supports alternative build scripts (e.g. build.gradle.kts). Please check it out and let us know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this gist solution  https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8694399:

download a script

```
$curl -L -s https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/8694399/raw/gradle-tab-completion.bash \
  -o ~/gradle-tab-completion.bash
```

and add to your `bash_profile` this string:

```
source ~/gradle-tab-completion.bash
```

Comment: @Kyll - It was at my suggestion that what had been a comment, should be promoted to being an answer. That way I could accept it and it seems that my upvote has balanced your downvote

Comment: @NickT, i guess Kyll was right - the answer was needed some improvements

Comment: Better use official gradle completion script from https://github.com/gradle/gradle-completion